# How to display post count in Categories metabox in dashboard?

Tags: wordpress

```
Dashboard -> Posts -> Add New
```

I would like to be able to see the number of posts in each category, withouth going to `Dashboard -> Posts -> Categories`.

I know it has an ID of `categorydiv` somewhere in the code. Maybe there is a way to change it in the code, but I am not sure where to find it.

How can I do it? Or is there a plugin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hooking into `the_category` and taking care of only applying it in the correct screen, we can add a category count just after its name.

```
<?php
/*
    Plugin Name: Category count in Meta Box
    Version: 0.1
    Plugin URI: http://stackoverflow.com/q/13117968/1287812
    Author: Rodolfo Buaiz 
    Author URI: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/12615/brasofilo
*/

// The hook "load-{$pagenow}" only runs in admin and in the specified page
add_action( 'load-post-new.php', 'add_filter_cat_so_13117968' );
add_action( 'load-post.php', 'add_filter_cat_so_13117968' );

function add_filter_cat_so_13117968()
{
    // Run only in correct post type
    global $typenow;
    if( 'post' != $typenow )
        return;

    add_filter( 'the_category', 'filter_cat_so_13117968' );
}

function filter_cat_so_13117968( $cat_name )
{
    $cat_id = get_cat_ID( $cat_name );
    $category = get_category( $cat_id );
    $count = $category->category_count;
    return "$cat_name ($count)";
}
```

[image: category counter in post meta box]